# My 'elseif' Statement Has a Bug

Tags: lua

```
   if message:sub(6, message:len()) == "%d+" then
        local a = message:find(" ")

        local hatId = message:sub(a + 1, message:len())

        local hat = game:GetService("InsertService"):LoadAsset(tonumber(hatId)):GetChildren()[1]
        hat.Parent = character
        print("Adding hat " .. hatId .. " to " .. player.Name)
    elseif message:sub(6, message:len()) ~= "%d+" then
        local a, b = message:find(" ")
        local c, d = message:find(" ", b + 1)

        local meshId = message:sub(b + 1, d)
        local textureId = message:sub(d + 1, message:len())

        local hat = game:GetService("InsertService"):LoadAsset(tonumber(meshId)):GetChildren()[1]
        hat.Parent = character
        hat.Handle.Mesh.TextureId = "http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=" .. textureId
        print("Adding hat " .. meshId .. " with texture "  .. textureId .. " to " .. player.Name)
    end
```

For some reason, after I type in `/hat hatIdHere`, it goes on to the `elseif` statement and says that there's an error at the `local hat = game:GetService(--[===[etc]===]` line.

There should not be an error because the code there shouldn't be running.  However, if I type in `/hat meshId textureId`, then it works.

Please help, I have no clue why this isn't working.  My `message` is a defined string.

Comment: You should use `message:sub(6, message:len()):match("^%d+$")` instead of `message:sub(6, message:len()) == "%d+"`.  And `not message:sub(....):match(....)` in the line `elseif .... ~= "%d+"`

Comment: Thanks for the help!  It works perfectly.